# Cómo puedo combinar de manera correcta php con html?

Tags: php, html

Me gustaría replicar este pedazo de código en otro lado pero php me lanza mensaje de error ( ejemplo  me lo detecta como cadena por obvias razones) al querer poner clase a una etiqueta en html.

*ejemplo de como me gustaría replicar el código pero agregando una clase a esa etiqueta html espero me puedan ayudar.*

```
<?php

while( $fila = $resul->fetch_assoc() ){
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>".$fila['Nombre']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$fila['email']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$fila['t_usuario']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$fila['telefono']."</td>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"update.php?id='$fila[t_usuario]'\">update |<a href=\"borrar.php?t_usuario='$fila[t_usuario]'\">Borrar</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas te ha servido, recuerda regresar acá y marcarla como útil o deja un comentario si algo no te funciona para tratar de mejorar las respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la [sintaxis alternativa](https://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) de `PHP`. Así el código se verá mas limpio y además podrás "manipular" el `html` sin problemas.

```
<?php while($fila=$resul->fetch_assoc()): ?>
  <tr class="ejemplo">
    <td><?= $fila['Nombre'];?></td> //Esto equivale a hacer echo
    <td><?= $fila['email'];?></td>
    <td><?= $fila['t-usuario'];?></td>
    <td><?= $fila['telefono'];?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

En [esta pagina](https://styde.net/como-combinar-html-y-php/) encuentras la explicación mucho más detallada.

Answer (score 1):

Hola para creo que lo que intentas hacer es ejecutar código PHP en un archivo html, para esto debes de crear un archivo con extensión php y dentro colocar tu código html, de esta forma podrás usar código php.

Por ejemplo:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head> </head>
    <body>
         <?php
          while($fila=$resul->fetch_assoc()){

        echo "<tr>"; 


        echo "<td>".$fila['Nombre']."</td>";


        echo "<td>".$fila['email']."</td>";


        echo "<td>".$fila['t_usuario']."</td>";


        echo "<td>".$fila['telefono']."</td>";


        echo "<td><a href=\"update.php?id='$fila[t_usuario]'\">update |<a href=\"borrar.php?t_usuario='$fila[t_usuario]'\">Borrar</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza comillas simples dentro de las comillas dobles para agregar una clase a una cadena HTML dentro de PHP, ejemplo:

```
while( $fila = $resul->fetch_assoc() )
   {
      echo "<tr class='ejemplo'>"; 
      echo "<td>".$fila['Nombre']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$fila['email']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$fila['t_usuario']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$fila['telefono']."</td>";
      echo "<td><a href=\"update.php?id='$fila[t_usuario]'\">update |<a 
             href=\"borrar.php?t_usuario='$fila[t_usuario]'\">Borrar</a></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
```